# psycopg2 i got the error message "where syntax 'column' is not in list error " using pyspark

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, psycopg2

Same as title

I'm Using AWS Glue, Script, Glue3 and Python3 also using psycopg2 library
When i delete AWS Aurora(postgresql) record

my syntax is very simple, like this

tuple_list : [(value1,value2),(value1,value2), ....]
value 1 : String, value 2 : timestamp

```
query  = "DELETE FROM {table} WHERE (col1, col2) IN ( VALUES %s)".format(table=table)
extras.execute_values(db.cur(), query, tuple_list,  template="(%s, %s)", page_size=2000)
db_conn.commit()
```

i got the message "where syntax 'col2' is not in list error"
i have no idea why i didn't work....

thx for your interesting and have a good day

```
all my error message 

Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 24) (IP executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1571, in __getattr__
    idx = self.__fields__.index(item)
ValueError: 'col2' is not in list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 604, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 594, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2916, in pipeline_func
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2916, in pipeline_func
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2916, in pipeline_func
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 418, in func
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 932, in func
  File "/tmp/job_test", line 136, in process_partition
  File "/tmp/job_test", line 88, in execute_batch_delete
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1576, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: col2

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:652)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2278)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Driver stacktrace:
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error message a traceback.

Comment: Best guess is that one of the tuples in `tuple_list` is missing it's second element so no match can be found for `col2`. As @snakecharmerb commented the complete error message would be helpful. FYI, `template="(%s, %s)"` is redundant as `%s` is the default and the length will be determine by the length of the first  tuple in the `tuple_list`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thx your comment and append my complete error message

Comment: The query you show is being executed by `psycopg2`, but the error message is coming from `pyspark`. Furthermore it looks like `pyspark` is eating the actual query(`psycopg2`) error. Have you looked at the Postgres log to see if it has useful information? I still believe the issue is that one or more  of the tuples in `tuple_list` is missing a value.